# dataframe append issue : trying to append dataframe one after the other into a list inside a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

[this is the op , where in the value in the month column has to be 1,2,3,4 but the 4th month value is overwriting all the previous value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgVQk.png)[Attached is the image of the data that I am trying to modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r06O6.png) list values appended is overwritten by the last value of the  for loop, not sure what is being missed here tried both concat and append , both of it does not give the expected output

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

file_name = r"file_path"

df1=pd.read_excel(file_name)
df1.dropna(axis=1, how='all', thresh=20, subset= None, inplace=True)
df1=df1[df1.col1 != "xyz"]
df2=df1.iloc[:,0:1]
df3=df1.iloc[:,2:]

######### first try ######################
## In this try the values in the list were all overwritten by the last 
values from the loop ##

df=pd.DataFrame([])
for i in range(len(df3.columns.values)):
     df4.assign(col1=lambda x: df2.iloc[:,0],
           col2=lambda x: df3.columns[i].year,
           col3=df3.columns[i].month,
           col4=df3.iloc[:,i]) 
     print(df4.head(2))
     df.append(df4)


########### second try #####################
## in this try the list was empty when printed##

df=[]
df4=pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
for i in range(len(df3.columns.values)):
     df4['col1']=df2.iloc[:,0]
     df4['col2']=df3.columns[i].year
     df4['col3']=df3.columns[i].month
     df4['col4']=df3.iloc[:,i]
     df.append(df4)
print(df)
```

### No error , expected result is that the list should have dataframes df4 values with respect to each iteration values of the for loop.

Results optained is last value from the loop is overwriting all the elements of the list

Comment: Can you give us a few rows of sample data?

Comment: St_No St_Na Jan-17                Feb-17            Mar-17             Apr-17
3011    stat1   $51,09,845.02 $37,06,047.49 $55,01,990.23 $63,23,336.33
3012    LA       $37,37,774.09 $28,86,163.37 $41,62,111.89 $49,25,217.29
3013    ROC    $35,79,789.01 $26,52,386.15 $38,35,170.78 $44,68,507.78

Comment: this is what the first four lines of the data looks like , I am not sure If can share the data by any other means , I am new to this and not sure about the possibilities .I am so sorry about that

Comment: Hi no worries, but better to edit your initial question than to paste in the comment section. Hard to read (how many values per row, are the white spaces new fields, etc. ?)

Comment: screenshots of the data and result have been added in the question

Comment: Found the answer , what is happening is that the list elements are all pointing to the same dataframe name . so all the elements of the list are overwritten by the latest df4 values.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(df3.columns.values)):                                                        
    y=1+i
    y=pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
    y['col1']=df2.iloc[:,0]
    y['col2']=df3.columns[i].year
    y['col3']=df3.columns[i].month
    y['col4']=df3.iloc[:,i]
    df.append(y)
```

Comment: this will give the expected answer